# Power Pivot comparativa IF+CALCULATE+FILTER

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Un día más recurro a ustedes para algo de ayuda con unas consultas en Power Pivot.

Estoy desarrollando unas tablas dinámicas alimentada por una tabla, el cual he subido a power query y posteriormente a Power Pivot.

He creado una serie de consultas con el cual trabajar.

Estoy teniendo especial problema con una de ellas.

Tengo unas serie de campos tipo fecha:

FECHA_PRIMERA_SOLICITUD ,
FECHA_REALIZACION ,
FECHA_INFO ,
FECHA_RECEPCION ,
ETC.

Hay una métrica principal del cual va beber los demás cálculos.
Qué es el "n.º de Solicitudes". Debo tener en cuenta otro campo llamado AÑO_INFORME.
El AÑO_INFORME es un campo agregado, donde el usuario va poder filtrar por año el informe, y como quiero que sea dinámico, debe poder devolverme el "count del n.º de solicitudes donde el AÑO_PRIMERA_SOLICITUD=AÑO_INFORME"

(*)El AÑO_INFORME se extrae del campo FECHA_PRIMERA_SOLICITUD por lo tanto siempre va a coincidir que haya datos respecto a las solicitudes al filtrar el campo AÑO_INFORME.

mi tesitura es la siguiente; estoy intentando usar está formula:

````
        COUNT('Tabla_DATO_BASE'[ID_SOLICITUD]);
         'Tabla_DATO_BASE'[YEAR_1RA_SOL] = 'Tabla_DATO_BASE'[YEAR_INFORME]
    )´´´

Y esto me arroja el siguiente error:

"Error semántico: la expresión contiene varias columnas, pero en una expresión de True/False que se usa como expresión filtro de tabla, solo puede utilizarse una columna"

También se me había ocurrido usar FILTER + SELECTEDVALUE:

```solicitud3:=
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Tabla_DATO_BASE'[ID_SOLICITUD]);
    FILTER(
        'Tabla_DATO_BASE';
       'Tabla_DATO_BASE'[YEAR_1RA_SOL] = SELECTEDVALUE('Tabla_DATO_BASE'[YEAR_INFORME])
    )
)
´´´
Pero resulta que no existe esa función en Power Pívot, lo que me llevo a usar IF + HASONEVALUE + VALUE:

```solicitud3:=IF(
    HASONEVALUE('Tabla_DATO_BASE'[YEAR_INFORME]);
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT('Tabla_DATO_BASE'[ID_SOLICITUD]);
        'Tabla_DATO_BASE'[YEAR_1RA_SOL] = 'Tabla_DATO_BASE'[YEAR_INFORME]
    );
    BLANK()
)
´´´
Esas son las opciones probadas y me dan error. 
La verdad que ya no sé como seguir por que no tengo muy buen nivel aún con DAX mucho menos DAX en Power Pívot.

Agradecería enormemente vuestra ayuda o recomendación.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano
````